# How to prevent rendering the back window when popup panel is rendered or shown?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am having a problem like when a rendered the popup panel the back window or page where the call has been made rendered too. How can we stop the rendering of the back window. Also note that i am using Jsf 2.0 with Richfaces 4.0.

```
<h:form>
<rich:panel id="propertyPanel">

<rich:messages id="propertyFormMsg"></rich:messages>   

<a4j:commandLink
              action="#{addPropertyBean.createPropertyPreAction}"
              title="Add New Property"
              oncomplete="#{rich:component('savePropertyPopUp')}.show()"
              render="propertyPopUpOutPutPanel"
              >
              <a4j:param
                assignTo="#{addPropertyBean.selectedPropertyId}"
                value="#{addPropertyBean.selectedPropertyId}"></a4j:param>
              <h:graphicImage styleClass="imageLink" library="images"
                name="add.png" />
 </a4j:commandLink>

</rich:panel>
</h:form>
```

Here is my popup panel:

```
<rich:popupPanel id="savePropertyOfferPopUp" modal="false"
    resizeable="true" height="430" width="800">

    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Save Property " />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="controls">
      <h:outputLink value="#"
        onclick="#{rich:component('savePropertyPopUp')}.hide()">
                <h:graphicImage styleClass="noImageBorder" library="images" width="16" height="16" name="close.png" title="close" />
      </h:outputLink>
    </f:facet>

    <h:form id="propertyPopUpForm">
............
</h:form>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

Many thanks for anyone who will help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the a4j:commandLink that shows the pop-up, add the attribute: limitRender="true".  That will limit rendering to only the elements you have specified in the render="xxxx" list.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `onclick="#{rich:component('savePropertyPopUp')}.hide();return false;">` inside the rich:popup